# Substituir números por letras dentro do ArrayList

Tags: java, android

Estou criando uma calculadora onde, quero que os números dentro do `ArrayList`, sejam substituídos por letras no `textView`.

Exemplo: **1** = **A**, **2** = **B**, etc.

Com o código abaixo, consegui isso ao digitar os números. Ou seja, no `textView` aparecem letras ao invés de numero.

```all
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String >();
String string = "";
String string1 = "";
String string10 = "A";
String string2 = "B";
String string3 = "C";
String string4 = "D";
String string5 = "E";
String string6 = "F";
String string7 = "G";
String string8 = "H";
String string9 = "I";
String string0 = "J";


public void onClick1 (View v) {
    TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.caracteres);
    Button button = (Button) v;

    string = (String) button.getText().toString();

    if (!string.contains("+") && !string.contains("-") && !string.contains("*") && !string.contains("/")) {

        if (string.contains("2")) {
            string1 = string1+string2;
        }

        if (string.contains("3")) {
            string =string3;
        }

        if (string.contains("4")) {
            string =string4;
        }

        if (string.contains("5")) {
            string =string5;
        }

        if (string.contains("6")) {
            string =string6;
        }

        if (string.contains("7")) {
            string =string7;
        }

        if (string.contains("8")) {
            string =string8;
        }

        if (string.contains("9")) {
            string =string9;
        }

        if (string.contains("0")) {
            string =string0;
        }
    }

    textView3.setText(textView3.getText().toString() + string);
```

> Porém, no resultado, não consegui substituir, sempre permanece os numeros, já tentei de tudo.

```all
public void onClick (View v) {
    int calc= 0;
    int c = arrayList.size();



    TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.caracteres);

    if (arrayList.contains("8")) {
        string =string8;
    }


    //eg: array (2,+,3,*,4,-,3) size = 7, so (2,+,3,*,4,-,3)

    while (c!=1){

        if (c>3) {
            if (arrayList.get(3).contains("*") || arrayList.get(3).contains("/")) {
                if (arrayList.get(3).contains("*")) {calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2))*Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(4));}
                if (arrayList.get(3).contains("/")) {calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2))/Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(4));}

                //calc = 12 ;array = (2,+,3,*,4,-,3)

                arrayList.remove(2); // (2,+,+,*,4,-,3)
                arrayList.remove(2); // (2,+,3,*,4,-,3)
                arrayList.remove(2); // (2,+,+,-,3)
                arrayList.add(2, Integer.toString(calc)); // (2,+,12,-,3)
                c= arrayList.size(); // size 5

            }

            else {
                // (2,+,12,-,3)
                if (arrayList.get(1).contains("+")) {calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0))+Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));}
                if (arrayList.get(1).contains("-")) {calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0))-Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));}
                if (arrayList.get(1).contains("*")) {calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0))*Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));}
                if (arrayList.get(1).contains("/")) {calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0))/Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));}
                    // calc = 14
                arrayList.remove(0); // (+,12,-,3)
                arrayList.remove(0); // (12,-,3)
                arrayList.remove(0); // (-,3)
                arrayList.add(0, Integer.toString(calc)); // (12,-,3)
                c = arrayList.size(); // size = 3

            }

        }
            //size <= 3

        else {

            if (arrayList.get(1).contains("+")) {calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0))+Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));}
            if (arrayList.get(1).contains("-")) {calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0))-Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));}
            if (arrayList.get(1).contains("*")) {calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0))*Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));}
            if (arrayList.get(1).contains("/")) {calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0))/Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));}
                // calc = 9
            arrayList.remove(0); //(-,3)
            arrayList.remove(0); //(3)
            arrayList.remove(0); //()
            arrayList.add(0, Integer.toString(calc)); //(9)
            c = arrayList.size(); // size = 1 since is 1 loop ends.
            arrayList.add(string);
        }
    }


    textView3.setText(Integer.toString(calc));


}
```

Comment: Isso aí é java?

Comment: Bem vindo ao **SOpt**. Sugiro que faça o [tour] e visite a [help] para poder usufruir melhor do site. Também sugiro que veja a página pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, isso irá te ajudar nas próximas perguntas. Clique em [edit] na sua pergunta e adicione qual a linguagem de programação você está usando e, se possível, remova parte código (apenas o que for trivial) deixando só o que é realmente essencial para te ajudarmos.

Comment: @rray, sim é java.

Comment: @jbueno, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Eu queria comentar, mas parece que não tenho reputação suficiente. Talvez eu não resolva o seu problema, mas posso te dar algumas dicas:

- 1 : Se você está implementando uma calculadora a estrutura de dados que eu recomendo é a **Pilha** (Stack). Eu percebi que você está se matando para tratar os valores que você pega da sua **ArrayList**. Se vocẽ usar uma **Stack** essas operações se tornam muito mais simples. Basicamente, bem resumidamente, você empilha (**push**) todo o input e depois vai desempilhando (**pop**) e tratando os números e operadores. Acho legal você dar uma pesquisada.
- 2 : Existem muitas variáveis com o mesmo propósito no seu código. Você pode agrupar todas em um único vetor. No lugar de **string0**, **string1**, **string2**,... você pode simplesmente fazer:

  ```
  String[] string = new String[10];

  int i;
  char letra;

  for(i = 0, letra = 'A'; i < 10; i++, letra++)
    string[i] = "" + letra;
  ```
- 3 : Na verdade, eu nem usaria váriavel/vetor para fazer o que você está tentando. Se você quer substituir as letras por números (ou vice-versa), você pode usar a função **.replace** da string e já considerar todos os casos. No exemplo abaixo, essa linha troca todos os números pelas respectivas letras (caso exista na string):

  ```
  string = ((((((((string.replace("2", "B")).replace("3", "C")).replace("4", "D")).replace("5", "E")).replace("6", "F")).replace("7", "G")).replace("8", "H")).replace("9", "I")).replace("0", "J");
  ```
- 4 : Se você ainda quiser trabalhar com as suas condições, eu recomendo trocar **if** por **switch** ou o seu **.contains** por **.equals**. Se você não conhecer, vale a pena dar uma pesquisada.

Espero que você tenha sucesso no seu projeto, se tiver algo que eu possa ajudar, só da um toque.